# Show for any permutation of $N$ there exist integers $\{a,a+d,a+2 d\}, (d>0)$ such that $f(a)<f(a+d)<f(a+2d)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, permutations, contest-math

Show for any permutation there exist integers $\{a,a+d,a+2 d\}, (d>0)$ such that $f(a)<f(a+d)<f(a+2d)$

Comment: Any permutation of what i.e. what is the underlying set to which the permutation applies? Is $f$ the name of the permutation? or is the permutation $\sigma_n$ or $\sigma_1$, in which case where does $f$ come in?

Comment: They are all permutations of the natural numbers, sorry I forgot to include this. For example $\sigma_1$ is a permutation of $N$.

Comment: A permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ can move infinitely many elements, so iduction would in any case be hard when you make the step from the finite to the infinite. Hint: Let $a = f^{-1}(0)$ (or $f^{-1}(1)$ if you consider $0$ unnatural). Try $d = 1$ first. If that doesn't work, try $d = 2$. If that … Why does that guarantee to find a $d$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't quite follow your first statement, I thought that was what induction was good for. To the hint, I think this would work because there is no largest integer?

Comment: What type of induction are you considering? Ordinary induction stays in the realm of finite ordinals. But a generic permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ moves infinitely many elements, so you need to step beyond finite. If you do transfinite induction, the case of limit ordinals is often more difficult than the step from an ordinal to its successor. (And here, I have no idea how one would make the step from permutations that move only finitely many elements to permutations moving infinitely many.)

Comment: Regarding the hint, yes and no. That there is no largest integer of course plays a role, but that's comparatively minor. The key is something else.

Comment: I see, I'll read up on transfinite induction! I am working on the hint!

Comment: It seems like it has something to do with the fact that if we don't ever find a d that works, we will end up dealing with negative numbers, which is impossible. Am I on the right track?

Comment: That's the right track. Now try to make it precise. (And, just in case, let me note that we need not try $d = 3$ [and lots of other numbers], that would only muddy the argument.)

Comment: I think I got it. Since $f(a) = 0$ we must have that f(a+d)>0 because of the bijection. Then either $f(a+2d)>f(a+d)$ or it is smaller. In the first case we are done. In the second case, consider $f(a+4d)$, now either it is bigger than $f(a+2d)$ in which case we are done, or it is smaller, then compare $f(a+4d)$ and $f(a+8d)$ and continue this until in the worst case we will have $f(a+nd) = 1$ where is even (this is because of no largest integer). then of course we must have that $f(a+2nd)$ is bigger than $f(a+nd)$ and $f(a)$!

Comment: Right, but you should better write $f(a + 2^kd)$ than $f(a+nd)$, since we only look at steps $2^kd$.

Comment: Oh yes...whoops, it's late! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sketch of a possible proof: for any $a$ we may find some $d$ such that $f(a+d)>f(a)$. Moreover, every $d\geq d_0$ does that. If some $d\geq d_0$ is such that $f(a+2d)>f(a+d)$, we are done. Otherwise we may assume that for any $d\geq d_0$ we have $f(a+2d)<f(a+d)$. However, that implies:
$$ \ldots < f(a+8d)<f(a+4d)<f(a+d) $$
so $f(a+2^{2+f(a+d)}d)<0$, contradiction.