# For any $f:\mathbb{Z_+}\to \mathbb{Z_+}$ there exist $f(a)\le f(a+b)\le f(a+2\cdot b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, functions, contest-math, natural-numbers

I am preparing for the USAJMO, however I got stuck on the following question. I would really appreciate any help/hint.

> For any function ( not necessarily having Bijectivity ) $f:\mathbb{Z^+} \to \mathbb{Z^+}$ :
> Prove that there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ so that $f(a) \le f(a+b) \le f(a+2 \cdot b)$.

I can prove it pretty easily if $f$ is a monotonically increasing/decreasing function. However I have no clue how to prove the general case where $f$ is not necessarily monotonic. Any help is appreciated.

OP thinking :
A point I already got : monotonically decreasing function must have a lower bound, .... so if it is eventually from some value $f(x)$ must be the lowest value onwards ....
But I am not so sure when/if function $f$ values change up/down all the time ....

Comment: How long can a strictly descending sequence of positive integers be?

Comment: That point I already got it -- monotonically decreasing function must have a lower bound, so if it is eventually from some value f(x) must be the lowest value onwards. But I am not so sure if function f values change up/down all the time.

Comment: Well you have to think a bit, then - you aren't given very much information: can you organise a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Please take $a$ such that $f(a)$ is the lowest. Then, take $b(> a)$ such that $f(b)$ is the lowest  in $\{f(c)\mid a<c\}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f$ be a bijection $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ , prove there exist positive integers such that...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001632/let-f-be-a-bijection-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-prove-there-exist-p)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1455575/42969

Comment: Your Suggestions are very close & related & useful , though not Duplicates , @MartinR , because the Question here does not involve Bijectivity : It involves $\le$ [ not $\lt$ ] to high-light that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! In general , the Question Post has to include some attempts/efforts , to avoid closure. Here you have your attempts/efforts in a comment , @user908645 , which you should move into the Question Post itself , to get it reopened.

Comment: @Yos your solution is partially right as c-b might not be equal to b-a

Answer (score 4):

When Domain & range are Positive Integers , there must be some minimum value of $f$ , which we can use.
Let that minimum occur first at $a$.

**(CASE A)** When that minimum occurs again later at $a+b$ , then we have what we  wanted : $f(a) = f(a+b) \le f(a+2b)$ : we do not have to worry about the value at $a+2b$ , because it can not be less than the minimum.

**(CASE B)** When that minimum never occurs again , then we have more work to try out.

**ALGORITHM :**
Let us take $b = b_1 = 1$ , then $f(a) \lt f(a+b_1)$ according to the Criteria for our Case.
Check the value $f(a+2b_1)$ :
**(CASE B1)** If it is $f(a+b_1) \le f(a+2b_1)$ , then we have what we  wanted : $f(a) \lt f(a+b) \le f(a+2b)$ where $b=b_1$ : we can terminate our algorithm.
**(CASE B2)** If it is $f(a+b_1) \gt f(a+2b_1)$ , then we do not yet have what we  wanted.
Consider the value $c_1 = f(a+2b_1) - f(a)$
We will update $b_2=2b_1$ ( In general , $b_{n+1}=2b_{n}$ ) & then we go back to algorithm with the new value of $b$.
We know that algorithm will eventually terminate & we will eventually get the $b_n$ because $c_1 \gt c_2 \gt c_3 \gt c_4 \gt c_5 \gt \cdots \gt 0$ is impossible : In very iteration of the algorithm , $c_n$ , which is the gap between $f(a)$ & $f(b)$ , is reducing & that gap will go to $0$ eventually.
**When the algorithm terminates , we will have $f(a) \lt f(a+b_{n}) \le f(a+2b_{n})$ where $b = b_{n}$**

**VISUALIZATION :**

CASE B2 will look like this :

[image: f converging]

Here , the yellow lines indicate the gaps which are reducing. The gaps can not reduce arbitrarily & must eventually reduce to $0$ & the algorithm must terminate with CASE B1.

Comment: This solution is great, now I know where I have failed to do after locating the smallest value of $f(a)$. Does that mean we can easily extend this to $f(a)<=f(a+b)<=f(a+2b)<=f(a+3b)<=f(a+4b)...$

Comment: Nice to know that you liked this answer & that it was useful to you , @user908645 , to get more intuition into the matter here ! I think we can extend this like you want , though it might not be so easy , because the "gap" might not reduce the way we want. Consider $f(a+3b)<f(a+2b)$ : then we want $f(a+3b)$ close to $f(a)$ to let us update to the new $b$ value , though it may occur that $f(a+3b)>f(a+b)$ : the "gap" was not reducing ! We will have more work to try out here.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:
Let $S$ be the image of $f$. By the well-ordering principle, it has a minimum element, say $f(a)$. Pick the smallest such value of $a$. Then if $f(a+b) = f(a)$ for some $b>0$, we are done. Otherwise, let $S = \mathrm{Im}(f) - \{f(1),f(2),\ldots , f(a)\}$. Note that $S$ is non-empty. Again, we can take $f(a+b)$ which is the smallest value in $S$. Pick the smallest such value of $b$. Then, $f(a+2b)\ge f(a+b)$. Thus:
$$\boxed{f(a)\le f(a+b)\le f(a+2b)}$$

Comment: Nice thinking , though there are two issues here (1) the "obviously ..." bit is not true : $f(a+2b)=f(a)$ might mess things here (2) the "this is easily taken care of" bit has to be taken care of.

Comment: @Prem if we have $f(a+2b) = f(a)$, then $f(a+b) = f(a) = f(a+2b)$ by definition of $b$. I will add the easily taken care of part

Comment: [ +1 ] It all makes sense now after your edits ! Thanks !